# Why is the variable unassigned?

Tags: c#, razor

The d in the second if statement is out of scope (the error  is 'Use of unassigned local variable 'd'') Why? And how do I fix this?

```
 @{string d;}
   @foreach (var l in c.TimeAvailables) { 
   <div class="day @l.Day @c.id " data-day="@l.Day" data-bgtime="@l.BegginingTime" data-endtime="@l.EndTime">
   <div class="dayDisplayed">
   @if (l.BegginingTime != null)
       {
                      {d = l.Day; }
  <b class="time @l.id">From:</b> <span class="beTime" data-id="@l.id">@string.Format("{0:hh:mm tt}", new DateTime().Add(l.BegginingTime.HasValue ? l.BegginingTime.Value : new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0)))</span>
    <br />
   <b class="time @l.id">Until:</b><span class="enTime" data-id="@l.id">@string.Format("{0:hh:mm tt}", new DateTime().Add(l.EndTime.HasValue                ? l.EndTime.Value : new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0)))</span>
       }
@if (l.BegginingTime == null && d != l.Day)
  {
<b class="time @l.id"></b> <span class="beTime" data-          
 id="@l.id">Unavailable</span>
 <br />
 <b class="time @l.id"></b><span class="enTime" data-id="@l.id"></span>
    }
   </div>
```

}

Comment: If `l.BegginingTime == null` then `d` won't be assigned, therefore you can't read it. Just declare it as `string d = null;`

Comment: Try @{string d = string.Empty;}

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks!!

Comment: "Use of unassigned local variable" has nothing to do with being out of scope. If you have the actual error message, why did you pretend it was a different one?

Comment: d is only ever assigned in the case that `l.BeginningTime` is not null. Therefore checking it in the condition after confirming that `l.BeginningTime` is null is an unnecessary check.

Comment: I changed the title to accurately reflect the actual error you were getting. If it seems a little too much like the question answers itself, well...

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is d is unassigned:

Try

```
 @{string d = string.Empty;}
```

Alternatively as @Lucas suggested you could assign to null.